# Increase horizontal offset of Bootstrap tooltips

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to increase the tooltip offset for Bootstrap tooltips? There's nothing in the docs. The tooltip is obscuring the target area in some cases and preventing clicking.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: Have you tried to change the tooltip direction with the `data-placement` attribute?

Comment: Got some example markup? Have you followed this:
Tooltips in input groups
When using tooltips and popovers with the Bootstrap input groups, you'll have to set the container (documented below) option to avoid unwanted side effects.

Comment: Sorry for being AWOL - thanks for the container idea.

Answer (score 7):

You can try something like this..

```
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").hover(function(){
    $('.tooltip').css('top',parseInt($('.tooltip').css('top')) + 15 + 'px')
});
```

This would increase the vertical offset, but should work for horizontal if you use 'left' instead of 'top'.

Custom tooltip position on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/59977

Answer (score 1):

This example offsets to the right (i.e. increases the left position). NB: Added delay for the 'hide' for emphasis only. I check for the event type as well as the hover is fired on mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip({delay: {hide: 1000}});
$("[data-toggle=tooltip]").hover( function(e){
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter')
        $('.tooltip').css('left', parseInt($('.tooltip').css('left')) + 15 + 'px');
});
```