# angularjs ng-repeat bootstrap position

Tags: angularjs, position, tooltip, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a **bootstrap tooltip** within an **angular ng-repeat** - its ok except I cant see how I can change the position of the actual tooltip, by default it will popup centred above the icon but I'm looking to have it left aligned from the icon - see image to see what I mean...

[how to change bootstrap tooltip alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ss5.jpg)

I cant hardcode it as such, as it will be available on separate columns on the same row, so I cant say in CSS its 80px from the left of screen ...typically (its never that easy)... 
:-)
if you have any advice...appreciated- thanks

Answer (score 0):

try use attribute "data-placement", Example:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Hover</a>
```

Here doc tooltip Bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: hi thanks for that , but in my case I will be showing the tooltip above the item, but it seems that when you use the top/bottom 'data-placement' its actually aligning the tooltip centred from the item if you know what I mean?, I'm looking to have some sort of dynamic offset from the items position (ie: current-item-position-offset: -80px) or something ...if its possible...

Comment: two optons:
1. create styles Example:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h

2. use directive angular  "http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip"
and add class css with properties.
example:
YOUR-CUSTOM-CLASS:{ margin-top:80px; }
<input type="text" uib-tooltip="here title" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'" tooltip-class="YOU-CUSTOM-CLASS">

Comment: ok ...not being lazy or anything but my CSS is not great(thought I could avoid another directive), have u happen to have seen an example out there of this problem.. by any chance?

Comment: here answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605972/increase-horizontal-offset-of-bootstrap-tooltips

here DEMO
http://www.bootply.com/59977#